# Maximum likelihood not working in QGIS SCP?

Tags: qgis

I was trying to use maximum likelihood in SCP QGIS, but a warning come out "Information [18]: Select at least one signature", and when I selected all signature, it still won't run.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After reading [here](http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2014/08/minor-update-semi-automatic_17.html) and talk with the developer, finally, managed to resolve this.

It is because I was using drone imagery with a normal and IR camera as sensors. With this kind of camera, there is this alpha band which have all same value. When I remove alpha band from raster file, leaving RGB only, the problem is resolved.